# Can fee related expired patent be renewed?

Tags: expired-patent

Does this mean patent is expired and I can manufacture the apparatus? can former patent owner renew it and how would it affect my production?

2014-04-08   Anticipated expiration
2019-10-31   Application status is Expired - Fee Related

Is this patent valid worldwide or it has to apply for each and every country?

Thanks

Mary

Comment: It would be best if you please provide the patent number. However if the anticipated expiration would have been 2019-10-31, then it would have expired by now (this actual day in fact) even if the fees were up to date.

Comment: We really need more info to be very helpful - and yes patents are territorial and only valid in the location they are granted.

Answer (score 1):

Google used to have trouble calculating the expiration date where there is a patent term extension. I hope they fixed that, but in case they haven't, if you are really concerned about this patent, you should calculate the expiration date yourself.

Substantively, even an expired patent can be asserted for infringement that took place during the time the patent was live (going back 6 years). So if you did infringe, there "mere" expiration of the patent doesn't get you fully off the hook. Similarly, an expired patent can sometimes be brought back into force, as described at https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2590.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't state the patent number, we can't check the official status in the US Public Pair. What I can do is answer your second question.

> Is this patent valid worldwide or it has to apply for each and every
>   country?

Patents are territorial. A US patent applies only in the US. To get patent protection in any other country requires a patent in that country.